# Canvas not drawing all images only on certain mobile devices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas, drawimage

I'm having a problem with the canvas not drawing all images (only some are drawn) on specific devices.
To be exact **Mobile Chrome (Samsung)**, I have not met this issue on any other device so far.

```js
  const drawSymbol = (
    ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D,
    symbol: CardSymbol,
    image: HTMLImageElement,
  ) => {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      ctx.drawImage(
        image,
        symbol.x,
        symbol.y,
        symbol.width,
        symbol.height,
      );
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    if (canvas) {
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      if (ctx) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        for (const symbol of card) {
          const image = images[symbol.image.id];
          if (image.loadedImg) {
            drawSymbol(ctx, symbol, image.loadedImg);
          } else {
            const img = new Image();
            img.onload = () => {
              image.loadedImg = img; // Cache loaded image
              drawSymbol(ctx, symbol, img);
            };
            img.src = image.src;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, [card]);
```

Some images seem to draw and some simply don't. I've noticed that sometimes a portion of the images draw and then get removed and a different portion is drawn, but I cannot confirm if this actually happens as it's hard to spot (milliseconds).
Does anyone have an idea why could this be happening?

Do you think that a single `window.requestAnimationFrame` for all images could solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to fix it by gathering all the images first and then drawing the images with only one `requestAnimationFrame`.

```
const getHtmlImage = async (imageId: number) => {
  const image = images[imageId];

  if (image.loadedImg) {
    return image.loadedImg;
  } else {
    return new Promise<HTMLImageElement>((resolve) => {
    const img = new Image();
      img.onload = () => {
        image.loadedImg = img; // Cache loaded image
        resolve(img);
      };
      img.src = image.src;
    });
  }
};

...

const htmlImagesPromises = card.map((symbol) =>
  getHtmlImage(symbol.image.id),
);
const htmlImages = await Promise.all(htmlImagesPromises);

window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  ...
});
```